# How can I list the files in the folder with checkedlistbox?

Tags: c#, forms

How can I list the files in the folder with checkedlistbox?

I am a student and need help with the project.

Comment: You should show some own effort. SO is not a source for free homework service

Comment: Isn't the idea of a homework or school project to improve your skills by finding out a solution on your own?

Comment: use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to get filenames, put them into listbox... You should try something and then ask for specific problem

Comment: Your question is *too broad*. Try to break-down your problem into smaller problems and solve one at a time. Also the internet is full of information to help you solve this

Comment: private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\\";
            fileDialog.Multiselect = true;
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string[] files = fileDialog.FileNames;

Comment: I tried it but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a Button and a CheckedListBox on a Form. See button handler example:

```
    private void btnListFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
            {
                // cbListBox.Items.Add(fileName); // Full path
                cbListBox.Items.Add(fileName.Split('\\').Last()); // Just filename
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Note that `Directory.GetFiles` will lock your app for some time if there are too many files inside. In this case consider to iterate them using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` method.

Comment: Thanks i got the opewix answer.

Answer (score 0):

//Get file list with full path

```
string[] filesFullpath = Directory.GetFiles(@"Directory Path");
```

//get just file names

```
files = filesFullpath.Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s)).ToList();
```

//set checkedListBox datasource

```
checkedListBox1.DataSource = files;
```

Full Code

```
string[] filesFullpath = Directory.GetFiles(@"Directory Path");
files = filesFullpath.Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s)).ToList();
checkedListBox1.DataSource = files;
```